# Jquery ChangeEvent global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, global-variables

i have this code.

```
    var anyChange = false;

    function init(){

    $('.saveSettingsEvent').bind("change",function(){
          anyChange  = true ;   
        }
     );
    }
```

...

```
 onload='init()
```

The event is fired , but the variable (anyChange ) remains 'true' , only inside anonymous function .

I use :

- Jquery 1.8.2
- JqueryMobile 1.2

where I'm wrong ? 
Thnx !

Comment: How do you check that the variable was not changed from the outside?

Comment: A little bit of advice for you  next question, you should provide more info and code then this. Where did you check it? How did you check it?

Comment: `if(anyChange != false ){

    // Do Somthing
    }`


Or 


`if(anyChange == true){

    // Do Somthing
    }`

Comment: please port your form markup.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example for you.

```
var anyChange = false;

$(function() {
    $('.saveSettingsEvent').bind('change',function(){
        anyChange  = true ;   
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
        alert(anyChange);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YuUVd/2/

It works as expected. anyChange is set to true and stays true.

So, if you need more help, we need more information.

I assume, that some other code sets your variable back to false or your change event is never triggered...

Comment: I use this code in a form. All inputs,selects,and checkboxes have this class ("saveSettingsEvent"). I tried to change name of "anyChange" ... but still not working . Then I tried your code and still not working . The only solution that I see is insert into DOM tree with custom 'attr' or 'tag'

Comment: keep in mind, when the change event is triggered, sometimes you'll also need click or keyup. On an input the change event is triggered when you leave it...

Answer (score 0):

**Real Solution**

( Pending )

**Workaround**

I make a custom Tag with custom attribute at the end of the Body.

When the event is triggered , sets True the attribute **res**

```
$(function() {
    $('.saveSettingsEvent').bind('change',function(){
        $("#anychange").attr('res','true');  
    });

});
```

if

```
var resToSave = $("#anychange").attr('res');
if(resToSave == 'true'){
   // Do Something
   ...
   // Reset attr
   $("#anychange").attr('res','false');
}
```